# How do Ruby symbols work?

Tags: ruby, symbols

I read that Ruby has a language featured called "labels", how does that work?

Update:

I saw it at http://ruby.about.com/od/gems/qt/shorturl.htm where the author talks about a label at the bottom of the article with:

`puts ShortURL.shorten('http://ruby.about.com', :lns)`

Comment: The feature you are referring to is Ruby symbols.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding Symbols In Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341837/understanding-symbols-in-ruby)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think the author meant to say **symbols**.  You can read about them [here](http://glu.ttono.us/articles/2005/08/19/understanding-ruby-symbols), and the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Symbol.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've just consulted my "[Pickaxe](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/ruby/programming-ruby)" book and there's no such feature. Could it go by another name?

Answer (score 0):

The Rails framework has **labels** but these are just helpers for the HTML *label* tag.