# Ruby -- understanding symbols

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, symbols

I'm having a little trouble understanding how symbols work in my code.  I understand that they are essentially immutable strings, but I don't fully understand how symbols automatically "recognize" other parts of my code.

For example, in the program below, I pass two method objects to my math_machine methods, but to do so I use a symbol representing their name.  How does Ruby know that I am referring to those methods?

```
def plus x,y
    return x+y
end

def minus x,y
    return x-y
end

def math_machine(code,x,y)
    code.call(x,y)
end

puts math_machine(method(:plus),5,5)
puts math_machine(method(:minus),5,5)
```

Another example of symbols I don't understand is regarding encapsulation -- how do `attr_reader`, `attr_writer`, and `attr_accessor` know that the symbol that follows refers to an instance variable in my program?

If someone could explain to me the mysterious nature of symbols in Ruby (what is going on behind the scenes) that would be awesome!

Comment: Have you already read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341837/understanding-symbols-in-ruby)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, in the program below, I
>   pass two method objects to my
>   math_machine methods, but to do so I
>   use a symbol representing their name.
>   How does Ruby know that I am referring
>   to those methods?

This has nothing to do with symbols. You can even do `method('plus')` and you'll get the same result as method(:plus).

```
irb(main):001:0> def plus
irb(main):002:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> method(:plus)
=> #<Method: Object#plus>
irb(main):004:0> method('plus')
=> #<Method: Object#plus>
irb(main):005:0> method('plus') == method(:plus)
=> true
```

> Another example of symbols I don't
>   understand is regarding encapsulation
>   -- how do attr_reader, attr_writer, and attr_accessor know that the symbol
>   that follows refers to an instance
>   variable in my program?

These methods are meant to provide readers, writers, and accessors (r+w) to instance method. They just take the value of the symbol passed, and create the relevant methods.