# What is the colon operator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, symbols

When I say `{ :bla => 1, :bloop => 2 }`, what exactly does the `:` do? I read somewhere about how it's similar to a string, but somehow a symbol.

I'm not super-clear on the concept, could someone enlighten me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding Symbols In Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341837/understanding-symbols-in-ruby)

Comment: Try looking at this: [The Ruby_Newbie Guide to Symbols](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm)

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBXGBbEbXZY) tells you everything you need to know about symbols.

Answer (score 297, accepted):

`:foo` is a symbol named "foo". Symbols have the distinct feature that any two symbols named the same will be identical:

```
"foo".equal? "foo"  # false
:foo.equal? :foo    # true
```

This makes comparing two symbols really fast (since only a pointer comparison is involved, as opposed to comparing all the characters like you would in a string), plus you won't have a zillion copies of the same symbol floating about.

Also, unlike strings, symbols are immutable.

Comment: just wonder why literal string does not support string interning ?

Comment: @onmyway133 Because Ruby's strings are mutable. Interning only applies to immutable values.

Comment: a) Why is `"foo".equal? "foo"` false? b) Can you refer to a symbol anywhere, essentially making them like global variables?

Comment: @Arc676 1. `equal?` in Ruby does identity comparison. Each string literal, like `"foo"`, creates a new string instance. It works that way because strings in Ruby are mutable. 2. Symbols are global, but more like global constants than global variables, since symbols do not have state. Thus using symbols is not an antipattern in the way that global variables are.

Comment: @Arc676 `"foo" == "foo"` # => true

Answer (score 60):

Just to demonstrate some of the things mentioned in the answers:

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 1_000_000

print '"foo".equal? "foo" -> ', ("foo".equal? "foo"), "\n"
print '"foo" == "foo"     -> ', ("foo" == "foo"    ), "\n"
print ':foo.equal? :foo   -> ', (:foo.equal? :foo  ), "\n"
print ':foo == :foo       -> ', (:foo == :foo      ), "\n"

Benchmark.bm(10) do |b|
  b.report('string')     { n.times { "foo".equal? "foo" }}
  b.report('str == str') { n.times { "foo" == "foo"     }}
  b.report('symbol')     { n.times { :foo.equal? :foo   }}
  b.report('sym == sym') { n.times { :foo == :foo       }}
end
```

Running it outputs:

```
"foo".equal? "foo" -> false
"foo" == "foo"     -> true
:foo.equal? :foo   -> true
:foo == :foo       -> true
```

So, comparing a string to a string using `equal?` fails because they're different objects, even if they are equal content. `==` compares the content, and the equivalent checks with symbols are much faster.

```
                 user     system      total        real
string       0.370000   0.000000   0.370000 (  0.371700)
str == str   0.330000   0.000000   0.330000 (  0.326368)
symbol       0.170000   0.000000   0.170000 (  0.174641)
sym == sym   0.180000   0.000000   0.180000 (  0.179374)
```

Both symbol tests are basically the same as far as speed. After 1,000,000 iterations there's only 0.004733 second difference, so I'd say it's a wash between which to use.

Comment: Extremely helpful! On my system, `==` resulted faster than `.equal?` for both string and symbol comparisons. Symbol comparison resulted 3+ times faster than string comparisons.

Answer (score 34):

Symbols are a way to represent strings and names in ruby.

The main difference between symbols and strings is that symbols of the same name are initialized and exist in memory only once during a session of ruby.

They are useful when you need to use the same word to represent different things

Answer (score 25):

There're some quotes from the famous book [Agile Web Development with Rails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356549), which may be helpful to understand the *symbol* as well :

> Rails uses symbols to identify things. In particular, it uses them as keys when naming method parameters and looking things up in hashes.

```
redirect_to :action => "edit", :id => params[:id]
```

> You can think of symbols as string literals that are magically made into constants. Alternatively, you can consider the colon to mean "the thing named", so :id is "the thing named id".

Answer (score 8):

In ruby each object has a unique object identifier, if you write `puts "hello".object_id` in your irb and hit return for 2 different times, you will get 2 different returning value,but if you write `:hello.object_id` 2 times you will only get the same one returning value. 
That should have explained the difference.

Comment: Basically the colon operator is for assign a [tag:symbol]

Answer (score 3):

If you use `:foo => bar`, foo will be a symbol. The benefit to symbols is that they are unique. When you call on an item in the hash, you do `hash[:foo]`.

Symbols require less memory than strings, which also makes them useful if you want to make your program a little faster.

Answer (score 1):

All these answers omit one extra tantalising detail.. if you stringify the symbol :foo, you get.. guess what.. the string "foo".  Hence

```
irb(main):025:0>
irb(main):026:0> :foo
=> :foo
irb(main):027:0> "#{:foo}"
=> "foo"
irb(main):028:0>
irb(main):029:0> 'foo' <=> :foo
=> nil
irb(main):030:0> 'foo' <=> :foo.to_s
=> 0
irb(main):031:0>
```

Hence.. for Perl programmers.. it's Ruby's answer to the 'bare word'.

Answer (score 0):

It's a symbol. Basically, you are saying that the two elements of the hash have keys `bla` and `bloop`, much as if you had used the strings `"bla"` and `"bloop"`. However, they take up less memory than strings and are easier to type.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Java, you might be aware that Strings in Java are immutable. Symbols are similar in that sense in Ruby. They are immutable, i.e., any number of occurances of a particular symbol `:symbol` will map to only a single memory address. And, hence, it is recommended to use symbols wherever possible since it optimizes memory usage.

Comment: The fact that symbols are immutable ensures that they are always the same instance throughout your application and hence they are guaranteed to be the same object.

Check these references : http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm
http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/

You'll find loads more if you google.

Comment: I am talking about your analogy to Java. Java Strings are not analogous to symbols. Java string literals are but not all strings.

Comment: Perhaps my statement wasn't clear enough. They are analogous to each other only with respect to the fact that they are immutable.

Comment: @DhruvaSagar: The analogy would be better if you used Objective C’s `NSString`. There `"foo"` will always be equal to `"foo"`, because internally strings that are the same are just pointed to. The answer would still be confusing, though.