# what does ":foo" mean in ruby

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the colon operator in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337897/what-is-the-colon-operator-in-ruby)

While learning Ruby I've come across the ":" operator on occasion. Usually I see it in the form of

```
:symbol => value
```

what does it mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337897/what-is-the-colon-operator-in-ruby possible duplicate

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It just indicates a that it is a symbol instead of a string.  In ruby, it is common to use symbols instead of strings.

```
{:foo => value}
{'foo' => value}
```

It's basically a short-hand way of expressing a string.  It can not contain spaces as you can imagine so symbols usually use underscores.

Try this on your own:

```
foo = :bar
foo.to_s # means to string
baz = 'goo'
baz.to_sym # means to symbol
```

Comment: Actually, the bit about symbols not being able to contain spaces is false; a symbol can hold anything a string can hold.  `:"hello world"` contains a space, and yet it's a perfectly valid symbol.  The difference between a string and a symbol is that a symbol always takes the same spot in memory every time you reference the same symbol.  This is good in that it saves memory if you use it the right way; it's bad because it consumes memory if you don't. See: [Symbol](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html).

Comment: Boiling down symbols to "basically a shorthand way of expressing a string" is *very* wrong and misleading. Symbols are very much not Strings.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I don't think Symbols should ever be used as strings; that's one of the bad ways of using symbols, and is terrible, especially for web development.  Sorry if it came off that way.

Comment: @drderp: I think Andrew Marshall was referring to the answer above, not to your comment. Your comment is correct. The answer is plain wrong. It's a pity it got accepted.

Comment: @undur_gongor I should have posted my comment as another answer :/

Comment: @drderp I was replying to the answer, your comment is okay as undur_gongor says.