# Significance of colon : in Ruby

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding Symbols In Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341837/understanding-symbols-in-ruby)
>   [What is the colon operator in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337897/what-is-the-colon-operator-in-ruby)

I really feel naive asking this, but I'm going to go ahead and ask :

What is the importance of `:` in ruby ?

I have seen it being used in a number of places like `params[:id]` or like `x < :length`.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341837/understanding-symbols-in-ruby and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337897/what-is-the-colon-operator-in-ruby?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A colon denotes a "symbol". A symbol is like a string, but it is immutable (you can't change its contents). Behind the scenes, it also takes up less memory, since a symbol only needs to exist once in memory (i.e., two strings called "length" will exist twice in memory, but two symbols called :length will point to the same object).

Comment: I'd say a `:` followed by a word _denotes_ a symbol, whereas a `:` on its own will raise a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

`:length` means it is a Symbol

Symbols are Strings, just with an important difference, Symbols are immutable.

[RubyDoc:](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html) Symbol objects represent names and some strings inside the Ruby interpreter. They are generated using the :name and :"string" literals syntax, and by the various to_sym methods.

Here are some good places to learn more about symbols

- [The Ruby_Newbie Guide to Symbols](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm)
- [Understanding Ruby Symbols](http://glu.ttono.us/articles/2005/08/19/understanding-ruby-symbols)
- [The Difference Between Ruby Symbols and Strings](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/)

Answer (score 2):

It is syntax indication of type for interpreter.

```
0-9   numeric*
:     symbol
""    string
[]    array
{}    hash
```

- Patterns more complicated in reality.