# "convenience" methods of creating hashes

Tags: ruby

Here is how I've been creating hashes thus far (per Codecademy)

```
my_hash = {
  "pay" => "low",
  "vacation" => "yes",
  "parking" => "no"
}
```

And here is rubymonk's new convenience method of creating hashes.

```
chuck_norris = Hash[:punch, 99, :kick, 98, :stops_bullets_with_hands, true]
```

Are the colons in the second technique part of the syntax or parts of the string? And if they are just parts of the strings, why aren't the strings in quotes?

Comment: It has nothing particularly to do with hashes.

Comment: it is indeed a duplicate. Didn't know they were symbols objects. Going to go read that post now. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are the colons in the second technique part of the syntax or part of the string?

The `:` are not the part of the *Hash* creation syntax,You are seeing it there as your second example use symbols as keys. :punch,:kick,:stops_bullets_with_hands are `Symbol` objects.[`Hash::[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) is the method used to create the Hash object.

```
Hash[:punch, 99, :kick, 98, :stops_bullets_with_hands, true]
     |_________| |________|
     (key,value) (key,value)
```

In the second example,the keys are considered as symbols. But you can use string,fixnum etc. too.

Comment: ah - a totally new object type introduced into the lesson with no warning! So they are NOT part of the syntax for creating a hash. I should just look at :punch, :kick, etc as if they are integers or strings. Right?

Comment: @Taymon How? `Hash::[]` method need only `(key,value)` pairs,it doesn't matters what objects the `key,value` combinations should be..

Comment: This should be actually in the Rubymonk forum. But there is no such forum. The problem was, they introduced symbols (with colons) into a very basic-level lesson about creating hashes using a new technique. The colons looked like part of the new syntax. Thanks for clearing it up sirs!

Answer (score 0):

> Are the colons in the second technique part of the syntax or parts of the string? And if they are just parts of the strings, why aren't the strings in quotes?

Looking at the Rubydoc we can see that the `Hash::[]` method has three forms:

```
Hash[ key, value, ... ] → new_hash
Hash[ [ [key, value], ... ] ] → new_hash
Hash[ object ] → new_hash
```

Your specific example is an instance of the first case where a list of objects are interpreted as pairs of key-values. So calling:

```
Hash[a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

will pair:

- a => b
- c => d
- e => f

I think you are confused by the `:` syntax, for which you can [easily take a look at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337897/what-is-the-colon-operator-in-ruby) some topics here on SO. Just to summarize: the `:` in this case constructs a [`Symbol`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Symbol.html) object.

In conclusion:

```
Hash[:punch, 99, :kick, 98, :stops_bullets_with_hands, true]
```

can be represented as the following hash:

```
{
    :punch => 99,
    :kick => 98,
    :stops_bullets_with_hands => true
}
```

where `:punch`, `:kick` and `:stops_bullets_with_hands` are symbols and `99`, `98` and `true` the corresponding values.

To return the values you can simply use the `Hash#[]` method like this:

```
chuck_norris[:punch] # 99
chuck_norris[:kick] # 98
chuck_norris[:stops_bullets_with_hands] # true
```

Remember that you can convert a symbol to a string via the `#to_s` method:

```
:punch.to_s # "punch"
:kick.to_s # "kick"
:stops_bullets_with_hands.to_s # "stops_bullets_with_hands"
```