# Understanding Ruby on Rails function call with class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm fairly new to Rails but have a fairly extensive programming background. I'm working on a project and my partner told me to call this function:

```
UserStats.select("DISTINCT(car_id) as car_id").where(["age |~ >?", 25]).map(&:car_id)
```

He told me this statement will get me an array user car id's for all users over 25.

Now I'm not really sure I fully understand what's going on in this line. I know the UserStats is a class but I don't see a select method.

1. Is that an already defined method? Can I just call this line in a ruby function or do I need to initialize the class first?
2. Does the `car_id` need to actually be `:car_id"? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: select comes from extending ActiveRecord. :car_id is just ruby syntax for symbol.  Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337897/what-is-the-colon-operator-in-ruby

Comment: Are you familiar with OOP and concept of static/class methods?

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with OOP. I have many years of C++ and Python experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UserStats` is a model. It represents a table in your database.

`UserStats.select` is a query method to extract result from your model (and eventually database table). 
Read here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

`where` is a clause to your select which is equivalent to mysql where clause.

result returned is an array, `map` creates a new array containing the values returned by the block in your case with car_ids

Above all run this code in your `rails console` and you can see an equivalent database query generated for it. That may help you understand better. Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(car_id) as car_id FROM `User_Stats` WHERE (age >= 25)
```

This should return something like:

```
[#<UserStat car_id: "Z5w3iefxJh">, #<UserStat car_id: "SADH1243Ng">, ...]
```

`.map(&:car_id)` will now sanitize your resultant array as:

```
 ["Z5w3iefxJh", "SADH1243Ng", ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the UserStats class inherits from ActiveRecord, select is built in.  Ruby makes it really easy to do basic database manipulation through ActiveRecord.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html