# The thing with Ruby on Rails and Colons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I used to be more of a hobby Java guy and try to switch to Ruby on Rails right now.
But I'm having some difficulties, believe it or not, I like braces and semicolons..gives some orientation.

But here's the question:
Right now I'm taking an online course in RoR and it occured to me, that I'm always wrong on how to work with symbols, hashes etc.

Example 1:
Let's take a look at this single line of code for example:

```
form_for(:session, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}, url: login_path)
```

And this is how I read it:

Method / Function name is

```
form_for
```

Parameters parsed to this method are:

```
:session, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}, url: login_path
```

Let's break up those into

```
:session 

:html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"} 

url: login_path
```

How the heck should I know how to declare those parameters?
Why are :session and :html passend in as keys and url not? 
Is the :html symbol a Hashmap-symbol?

2. Example:

In an model File you declare an n:m relationship like this (for example users <-> stocks)

```
  has_many :users, through: :user_stocks
```

Ok, I get that the first argument is :users and the second is the same as

```
:through => :user_stocks
```

correct?

But in the same way, let's look at an routes.rb config from the same project:

```
  resources :user_stocks, except: [:show, :edit, :update]
```

Now we're using an array of keys on the except hash, correct?
It does get clearer when writing an question but still, is there a rule of thumb / convention on when to use

```
:name

name: value

:name => {values}? 

name: [values]
```

Or is it just an personal preference? In that case I should hope that my online teacher stays consistent..

Generally speaking, I'm very confused on how the parameter syntax convention is and when to use what (what type of argument).
Is it just because I am starting with Ruby or did I miss some piece of convention.

I hope my problem is kind of understandable and excuse my english - non native speaker.
I really like to get along with RoR but right now watching the online course sometimes leaves me more confused than before because if I would've done it by myself, I would've used a completely different way.

Comment: `:html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}` is an old Ruby syntax to declare hashes. It is the same as `html: {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}`

Comment: Your question is broad. Please read "[ask]". You can ask a specific question, or two closely related questions at once, but more than that results in a diluted question, which is undesirable as it makes it difficult for others to follow. Answers will also be broad and not concise, which, again, makes it difficult for others. Much of what you ask about is in tutorials and the documentation. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)"

Comment: Well, how do you know that you have to surround strings with quotes in Java?

Answer (score 8):

> How the heck should I know how to declare those parameters?

You look up the method in the docs and you read about it.

> Parameters parsed to this method are:
>
> ```
> :session, 
> :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}, 
> url: login_path
> ```
>
> How the heck should I know how to declare those parameters? Why are
>   :session and :html passend in as keys and url not? Is the :html symbol
>   a Hashmap-symbol?

In ruby, if you pass in a series of key-value pairs at the end of the argument list, ruby gathers them all into a hash and passes them as one argument to the method.  Here is an example:

```
def go(x, y)
  p x
  p y
end


go(:hello, a: 10, b: 20)

--output:--
:hello
{:a=>10, :b=>20}
```

Another example:

```
def go(x, y)
p x
p y
end

go(
  :session,
  :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}, 
  url: 'xyz'
)

--output:--
:session
{:html=>{:class=>"form-horizontal", :role=>"form"}, :url=>"xyz"}
```

> ```
> has_many :users, through: :user_stocks
> ```
>
> Ok, I get that the first argument is :users and the second is the same
>   as
>
> ```
> :through => :user_stocks
> ```
>
> correct?

Correct.  In old ruby, key-value pairs in hashes were written like this:

```
'a' => 'hello'
```

If the value was a symbol, then it looked like this:

```
'a' => :hello
```

If the key was also a symbol, then you wrote:

```
:a => :hello
```

In modern ruby, if the key is a symbol you can write:

```
a: 'hello'
```

which is a shortcut for:

```
:a => 'hello'
```

and if the value is a symbol as well, in modern ruby it looks like this:

```
a: :hello
```

which is a shortcut for:

```
:a => :hello
```

> ```
> resources :user_stocks, except: [:show, :edit, :update]
> ```
>
> Now we're using an array of keys on the except hash, correct?

The hash isn't named `except`, but otherwise you are correct.

> a rule of thumb / convention on when to use
>
> ```
>     :name             #  Single symbol argument
>
>     name: value       #  A key-value pair in a hash.  The key is a symbol.
>
>     :name => {values}?   #A key-value pair in a hash.  The value looks like a hash, but the syntax is incorrect.
>
>     name: [values]       #A key-value pair in a hash.  The value is your notation for an array.
> ```
>
> Or is it just an personal preference? In that case I should hope that my online teacher stays consistent..

Once again, a method can be defined to take any type of argument.  Because ruby variables don't have types, you have to check the docs.  If a method expects you to pass in a hash where the key :name has a value that is a hash, then you need to do that.  On the other hand, if the method expects you to pass in a hash where the key :name has a value that is an array, then you need to do that.

> Generally speaking, I'm very confused on how the parameter syntax
>   convention is and when to use what (what type of argument). Is it just
>   because I am starting with Ruby or did I miss some piece of
>   convention.

Ruby has a lot of shortcuts, which can be confusing to a beginner.  Then there is the whole `String v. Symbol` concept. If you can understand the practical difference between a Symbol and a String, then you will be ahead of the game.  A Symbol is like an integer.  So when ruby has to compare whether Symbols are equal, ruby compares two integers, which is fast.  If ruby has to compare Strings, then ruby has to compare the ascii code of each letter in one string to the ascii code of each letter in the other string until ruby finds a difference.  For instance, in order for ruby to compare the following two Strings:

```
"helloX" v. "helloY"
```

ruby won't find a difference until *after* it has made six integer comparisons:

```
'h' v 'h' => equal
'e' v 'e' => equal
...
...
'X' v 'Y' => not equal
```

On the other hand, if ruby were comparing:

```
:helloX  v.  :helloY
```

the Symbols are essentially stored as single integers, something like:

```
341343   v.  134142  => not equal
```

To compare them takes only a single integer comparison, so it's faster.  As someone is sure to point out, that isn't quite how Symbols are implemented, but the details don't matter.  It's sufficient to know that Symbol comparisons are faster than String comparisons, and as to why that is true the example above is sufficient to demonstrate there is at least one implementation where it can be true.

Answer (score 1):

### Hashes: hashrockets vs literal

In Ruby hashes can use either "hashrockets" or the newer literal notation (since Ruby 1.9):

```
# hashrockets
{ :foo => "bar" }
# literal
{ foo: "bar" }
```

They both do the exact same thing. They create a hash with the [symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943106/what-is-the-difference-between-a-symbol-and-a-variable-in-ruby) `:foo` as a key. The literal syntax is [now generally preferered](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#hash-literals).

Hashrockets should only be used today if you have something other than symbols as keys (you can have numbers, strings or any object as keys):

```
{ 1 => 'a', 2 => 'b' }
# using literals won't work here since it will cast the keys to symbols:
{ 1: 'a', 2: 'b' } # => { :1 => 'a', :2 => 'b' }
```

As Ruby is loosly typed hashes can contain any kinds of values:

```
{ foo: "bar" }
{ foo: [:bar, :baz] }
{ foo: { bar: :baz } }
```

### Hash options

In Ruby methods can recieve both ordinal arguments and a hash with options:

```
def foo(bar, hash = {})
  @test= hash[:] 
end
```

The hash options must come after the positional arguments in the arguments list.

```
# syntax error
foo(a: 2, "test")
# good
foo("test", a: 2)
```

When passing a hash options you can forgo the surrounding brackets as they are implied:

```
foo("test", { a: 1, b: 2 })
# same result but nicer to read 
foo("test", a: 1, b: 2 )
```

Ruby 2.0 introduced keyword arguments which reduces the amount of boilerplate code needed to parse the options:

```
def foo(bar, test: nil)
  @test= test
end

def foo(bar, test: nil, **kwargs)
  @test= test
  # all the options except test
  puts kwargs.inspect 
end

# will raise an error if the test key is not passed
def foo(bar, test:)
  @test= test
end
```

### Postitional arguments vs hash options

Postitional arguments are shorter and ideal where the order of the parameters is self explainatory:

```
class Number
  def add(x)
    @val += x
  end
end
```

When you have more complex methods with a large number of arguments it can be tricky to keep track of the order:

```
def book_flight(destination, seats, airline_preference= nil, special_meals= nil)

end
```

thats where hash options come in and shine as you can have an arbirtrary number of options and the program does not blow up because you forgot a nil in the call.

Comment: Be sure to check [the Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) as it explains most of other community conventions like when to use parens and `do ... end` over brackets.

Comment: there is also a huge difference between declaring parameters (which is done when you declare a method) vs the calling signature of a method which is how you then use the code.