# Can't get the hang of symbols in Ruby

Tags: ruby, symbols

I have been looking the past days how to understand Symbols in Ruby. I read every article on Google about Ruby symbols, most of them are bad explanations so I come here, and I see some questions about this topic exists, however I do not understand, sorry.

From what I have read I understand that symbols are immutable and unique, so the memory consumption and performance is better than regular strings.

**Question #1**
Are symbols purpose in life to serve the same niche as strings? Is the purpose of symbols to function as convenient constants without carrying a value, like the part after : is it the actual value?

**Question #2**
When do I actually KNOW where to use symbols?

I would highly apprciate your own explanations of symbols instead of linking to articles on Google (I ensure that I already read it!).

I do also apprciate your time if you can provide more info about symbols than what I already asked about here, because I do not understand them at all, not even what is stored in :symbol_something, is it a reference or what?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding Symbols In Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341837/understanding-symbols-in-ruby)

Answer (score 6):

symbols in ruby are a way to efficiently utilize immutable strings.  For example, suppose you want to use the string "my_key" as a hash key.  Simply using the string is a waste of both space and efficiency since each time you specify the hash key "my_key" you are creating a different string instance in a different memory location even though the string value contents are the same!  So if you have 100 instances of my_hash['my_key'] you have 100 instance of the string 'my_key'.  Not so with the symbol :my_key.  There is only ever one instance of :my_key no matter how many times you utilize it!

You should use symbols where you would normally uses an immutable string as an identifier.

Comment: Thank you, so it is really that simple?

Comment: @Frank Zimmer: Basically. Symbols aren't any kind of deep magic. The nice thing about symbols is more in the "why" than the "how." When you see a string, you need to wonder whether it's meant as text or as a special token (if you see the string `low` as an argument to a function, is that telling the function that something should contain the all-lowercase string "low," or that it should have low priority?). Strings in Ruby are there for the first case, symbols for the second.

Comment: @Chuck: Excellent explanation, you should have made it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way to understand this is to consider that String is a Ruby object and it is not specified to be immutable. As a result, a number of optimizations are unavailable to the language processor and a reader of the code may or may not understand whether a given string is functioning as a mutable data structure or as the key to something.

But symbols *are* immutable, so they have unique instances. They are also easy to type, and the use of a symbol clearly indicates *"identifier"* or *"token"* to anyone reading the code later.

Finally, class Symbol implements the *explicit conversion* `#to_s,` so symbols are safe to use in expressions where you know `#to_s` will be called, such as in [*ERB templates*](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/erb/rdoc/index.html) or in I/O operations.