# Is a variable the quintessential "pointer"? Is params[] a pointer? Is params[] a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, pointers, parameters

Please, do not attack. Here's the example and code that made me think about this.

I'm studying ruby on rails and am in the midst of the MVC and params[] operator. And have been laying down some proofs or something, reminders on the inside cover of my notebook dedicated to rails, anyway

```
"So we don't just want to call tweet #1. Tweet.find(1) isn't enough."
===> we need Tweet.find(params[:id])

params[:id] aka params = { :id => 1 }
```

So I was labeling the different parts to my self, starting with the hash. "The 1 is the value, the :id is the key, the "params" is the....pointer?

Is params a pointer? Is it a variable?

EDIT: Are there any other "variables" (for a lack of a better term) that accept :keys without values other than params? Is this a special type of "container" or is it normal to just accept :keys without values
EDIT2: Are all variables technically pointers? If this true, are :keys inside of hashes technically pointers as well? Haha if this is true params is a pointer pointing to a pointer, which sounds about right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're using the right terms here. Maybe this will help:

- The *params* token is a variable name that holds a reference to some object.
- Technically, *params* is a method that returns a reference to a Hash object.
- In practice, you treat params as a hash because `params.is_a?(Hash) == true`.
- The :id token is a Symbol object.
- In `params[:id]` the :id is the key for a hash value.

IMHO, it's generally not useful to think of objects in Ruby as pointers--unless you're deliberately using them that way for some reason. But yes, under the hood there are a lot of layers of indirection that turn C pointers into Ruby objects at runtime.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by saing it's a hash of hashes but i think you are wrong. It's just an hash, it's values are any kind of objects, strings, fixnum, arrays or hashes.

Comment: `params` in a typical rails app always contains non-hash values, namely `controller` and `action`. Your statement is misleading, IMHO.

Comment: `params` is actually a method that returns a reference to a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` (which subclasses `Hash`).

Comment: @muistooshort Absolutely. I *think* the argument is about how it's typically used, not how it's constructed. I've gone ahead and given the hash-of-hashes tag a wiki entry, so we can all at least be arguing about the same thing. :)

Comment: Shouldn't that be a *method-that-returns-a-hash-of-hashes* tag? Then we'd be arguing about the same thing :)

Comment: @CodeGnome: I still object this statement. hash-of-hashes is just one small part of everyday's work: handling posted forms.

Comment: I was also going to mention the "hash-of-hashes" thing--IMO it's worth mentioning that it always has top-level entries, and won't necessarily contain embedded hashes, under many circumstances. It's a minor point, but still valid.

Comment: "I think we've finally arrived at a place we can all agree on." [No we haven't :)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTl9zYS3_dc)

Answer (score 0):

params is a hash of variables that came over the HTTP request

Comment: oohh. Where do the params go? In the "path" (URI)? Probably. Could they go (come from) anywhere else?

Comment: It depends. On a get request like widgets/1 params[:id] would be the 1 passed in the URL. Or they may be sent over put or post for those kinds of requests. Further :id is a symbol which is like a string, but is a singleton do it only ever has one address in memory, so they get used all over the place in ruby/rails as keys

Comment: The semicolon doesn't go in the URL, the value that comes through the request gets assigned as the value in the hash, for which :id is the key. The route generally decides what parameters are accepted

Comment: @David URLs allow arbitrary characters, but that's a separate issue (and that's a colon). A `:` before a word in Ruby means it's a [Symbol](http://apidock.com/ruby/Symbol).

Answer (score 0):

`params` is a method returning a reference to a hash.

*(But in general it's referred to as "the `params` hash", not "the `params[]` operator".)*

Hashes can use symbols, as well as other data types, as hash keys:

```
[1] pry(main)> h = Hash.new
=> {}
[2] pry(main)> h[:foo] = 42
=> 42
[3] pry(main)> h[42] = :foo
=> :foo
[4] pry(main)> h
=> {:foo=>42, 42=>:foo}
[5] pry(main)> h[h[:foo]]
=> :foo
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "accepting `:keys` without values".

Symbols may also be used in other ways, for example, to refer to a method. An example would be when defining a `before_filter`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :init

  def index
    # etc
  end

  private

    def init
      # Does some stuff
    end
end
```

The `before_filter` method takes a symbol indicating a method to run before calling an action.

Symbols are *not* references, they are symbols, and evaluate to themselves. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341837/understanding-symbols-in-ruby).

Comment: `params` is a method that *returns* a reference to a Hash (HashWithIndifferentAccess actually).