# Understanding Ruby symbols

Tags: ruby

Symbols are immutable objects, are lightweight strings, and are not garbage-collectable. I don't understand how they work in a Rails route or path. For instance, in:

```
get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show'
```

`:id` will be replaced by a number, and we get something like `/patitent/1`. However `:id = 1` is not allowed. How is this assignment performed?

Comment: I believe it's not a symbol, merely a part of a route string, which Rails parses to find an indentifier.

Comment: I don't understand your logic. `'/patients/:id'` becoming `'/patitent/1'` does not mean that `:id = 1`. `'abc'.gsub(/./, 'x') # => 'xxx'` does not mean that `a = b = c = 'x'`.

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of immutability, being lightweight strings, or being garbage-collectable to your question.

Comment: Your claim that symbols are not garbage-collectable is wrong as of now.

Comment: @sawa I'd say you're being pretty rude, cut the newbie some slack will you?

Comment: Thank you for yor patience @sawa. The reference about garbage-collectable comes from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447537/using-ruby-symbols
I'm learning ruby, so I confused a symbol with a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `'/patients/:id'` is a normal Ruby string, and although the `:id` part looks like a symbol, it is not.

When Rails parses the string, it uses the colon to identify a parameter name in the path. When it sets the parameter from receiveing a request like `GET /patients/1`, it does not attempt to alter the symbol value, but does something like the following

```
params[:id] = '1'
```

Note I'm not 100% certain that is doesn't just use the string `"id"` as the key here. But either way you can see it does not alter any symbol value, but just uses the *name* of the symbol so you know which key it will be stored under in the params `Hash`

The similarity between `':id'` as part of the URL parameter definition and for when you use the `Symbol` literal `:id` might be confusing, but is a design choice shared used in Rack path handling engine so most Ruby web frameworks use the same style.