# what does `:` mean in private :getWidth, :getHeight?

Tags: ruby

what does `:` mean in `private :getWidth, :getHeight`?

```
# define private accessor methods
   def getWidth
      @width
   end
   def getHeight
      @height
   end
   # make them private
   private :getWidth, :getHeight
```

Comment: `:getWidth` and `:getHeight` are `Symbols` (btw by common Ruby conventions those methods should be named `get_width` and `get_height`). Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11447568/2483313

Comment: See the docs for [`private`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Module.html#private-method) for details about the arguments it takes

Comment: @spickermann `width` and `height` actually - prefixes should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

The `:` sigil in Ruby denotes a symbol. Symbols are immutable strings which are used as identifiers all over the Ruby language.

```
private :getWidth, :getHeight
```

Sets the visibility of the getWidth and getHeight method to private. Its an alternative way of writing:

```
private

def getWidth
  @width
end

def getHeight
  @height
end
```

Beyond that this code is very unidiomatic. [Getter methods in Ruby should not be prefixed](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#accessor_mutator_method_names) and [method names should always be `snake_case`](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars) and not `camelCase`.

```
private

def width
  @width
end

def height
  @height
end
```

Or:

```
private

attr_reader :height, :width
```