# fields_for passing value to my own helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an assignment with many assessments and am using fields_for to traverse the nested assessment information.

On the assessment I have an ID value that I want to translate to its name. I want to pass that ID to a helper and return back the string name but I can't seem to get to the ID value?

My code is

```
<%= form_for assignment do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :assignmentassessments do |ff| %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <% strength_name(:strength_id) %>
        </div>
```

And the helper is

```
module AssignmentsHelper
  def strength_name(id)

    if id != nil
      @strength = Strength.find_by(id: id)
      @strength.name
    end
  end
end
```

I am getting `undefined method name for nil:NilClass` because when I pass `:strength_id` it is coming through as `nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass symbol `:strength_id` as `id` this cause error:

```
def strength_name(id)
  # in this scope your argument id equal :strength_id
  # if :symbol return true
  # because in Ruby :symbol == true
  # but Strength.find_by(id: :symbol)
  # return nil 
  # @strenght equal nil
  # and raise undefined method name for nil:NilClass
  if id != nil
    @strength = Strength.find_by(id: id)
    @strength.name
  end
end
```

How you can solve this problem?

Just pass valid `id` to your helper.

Read [`Understanding Symbols In Ruby`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341837/understanding-symbols-in-ruby)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I'm still a bit confused about how to get the value. If I do `ff.text_field :strength_id` I get a text box with the right value in it

Comment: @user1107201 sorry but i can't understand what you mean, can you describe more info for me? what exactly you can't get?

Comment: I don't understand how I can pass `:strength_id` to my own helper and use the ID value to retrieve the matching name from the Strengths table the same way `ff.text_field` takes `:strength_id` and creates a text box and puts the actual id value into it

Comment: try `ff.object.strength_id` this should return same as  `assignment.strength_id`